# SSRS Strange Behaviour with BETWEEN

Tags: reporting-services

I got a strange behaviour from a report.
Suppose i've a query and the result of that query its something like 14.000 records.

Now, the waiting time for this query its really low.

But, if i put a between on a date (or date > something and date < something) as filter for the query (so i probably will have less records in output) the waiting time for the result its really really really long.

I don't think it's a query problem because if i dont use the between the reports show the result in 2-3 sec.

I don't understand why i get this problem.

Comment: Did you actually run those queries in DBMS and compared the results? Also, what DB is the data source for the report?

Comment: Is the date field you are using to filter part of an index? Are you manipulating the date as you are searching for it i.e. Where Cast(date as DATE) >= Something?

Comment: The same query have 20 seconds of wait time on Microsoft Sql Server Management Studio 2012. but on the ssrs its really bigger (something like double time)

Comment: @user3056839 The field its not a part of an index and i manipulate the  filter in this way `IVRSession.InviteTime > '14/02/2015'`

Comment: After some try the problems it seems about the use of ssrs parameters in the query code `IVRSession.InviteTime > @DataDa` (with @DataDa = '14/02/2015') its lower than `IVRSession.InviteTime > '14/02/2015'`

Suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

> After some try the problems it seems about the use of ssrs parameters
>   in the query code IVRSession.InviteTime > @DataDa (with @DataDa =
>   '14/02/2015') its lower than IVRSession.InviteTime > '14/02/2015'
>   Suggestion?

With bound variable instead of fixed value SQL Server soft parses the query, which can take less time than hard parsing. You can find more information about these at

http://tranpeter.blogspot.se/2013/10/using-bind-variables-on-sql-server-or.html

Comment: Today i've solved the problem. Was a Parameter Sniffing problem. Thanks anyway!